# Is it possible to make a help command per command? Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

What I'm looking for is to make a help command that will give info for a specific role. Basically something like this:

`/help` -> General help info
`/help mute` -> Mute help info
`/help ban` -> Ban help info

I tried making different commands like this:

```
@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx):
   await ctx.channel.send('this is a help command')
```

and

```
@commands.command()
async def help_mute(self, ctx):
   await ctx.channel.send('Mute help information')
```

but both commands would show the first command's message. -> `this is a help command`. Why is that and could it be fixed?
Any answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Groups` and `Subcommands` to do it like this, however I strongly advise *against* this because then you'd have to create a new help command every single time you create a command, and all of them are exactly the same (`await ctx.send("help_for_this_command")`).

One thing you can do is add the information in the `help` kwarg of a command when creating it:

```py
@commands.command(help="Mute help information")
async def mute(ctx, ...):
```

This way, the default `help` will take care of this. However, you can't really change how the text looks, as it'll just be formatted by Discord's default `help` implementation, so you'll have to live with the codeblock it sends.

If you don't want that, then what I *do* recommend is creating your own custom `Help` command (not just a command named "help", but a class that inherits from the [`HelpCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=help#discord.ext.commands.HelpCommand) class & overrides functions where necessary). Then you can create a database (or JSON file) with the information for every command, and just get that.

```json
{
  "mute": "Mute help information",
  "ban": "Ban help information",
  ...
}
```

and a **very simplified** version of your `help` command would revolve around something like this:

```py
async def command_callback(self, ctx, *, command=None):
    if command is not None:
        if command in json_file:
            await ctx.send(json_file[command])
        else:
            await ctx.send("This is not a known command.")
```

Which is a **lot** cleaner than a huge chain of `if/else` statements checking which command was called.

If you want to see how the default help is implemented (to get an example of how to create yours), you can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/help.py#L255) on the Discord.py GitHub repo. Keep in mind you only have to override the functions you want to change - if the default behaviour does what you need then there's no need to copy paste the implementation into yours (as the base class's functions will just be called automatically).

### EDIT:

Łukasz Kwieciński linked a useful [`guide`](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96) with very easy steps explaining how to create your own `HelpCommand`. This will probably help you out a lot as well.

Comment: This also works and is a great idea for code efficiency, however for a starting off coder, this could possibly be too advanced and may not know exactly how the code works, both answers are both correct, they are just required for different skill levels.

Comment: This isn't about efficiency, `if/else` is slower than a ``dict`` but assuming he doesn't have millions of them it won't be noticeable. If he has 50 commands & wants to change how his help is sent, he has to do it 50 times. It's a huge burden & like I said a pain to maintain. It's also better to learn proper code the first time around.

Comment: I see, well I'll stick with the other answer I got till I get a bit better at programming. This looks really cool tho. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could take it as a parameter to pass with the help command. This would work by including an optional input after the help command, it would look like `/help ban` or `/help [category]`

A simple way of doing this would be, if the optional parameter wasn’t passed, it would send just the help command with no category. When the user includes a provided category, it would send help with that category. Here is it implied to your command.

```py
@commands.command()
async def help(self, ctx, category=None):
   if category == None:
       await ctx.channel.send('this is a help command')
       return
   if category == "ban":
       await ctx.channel.send('this is a ban and this is how to use it....')
       return
    if category == "mute":
       await ctx.channel.send('this is a mute command...')
       return
    else:
       await ctx.channel.send('Please provide a valid category')
       return
```

Comment: Woah programming will always suprise me. I did not know that you can use categories like this. To be honest with you this will help me a lot with other projects too... Let me try this and I'll tell you if it works! Appreciate the help

Comment: While this _works_, it's a very ugly solution & hard to maintain once you get more commands. Hardcoding things with `if/else` statements is never the way to go.

Comment: Well for now I'll just stick with this. When I get better at programming I may change it but I think for now this code helps a lot. Also it worked perfectly fine but I have a question. Shouldn't it be `if category == None:` and `elif category == "mute":`?

Comment: @xXSkillexZ Yes, you can do that, but the solution above has `return` statements in every `if`, meaning that if one of them succeeds the function returns & the others below aren't checked anymore. PS use `is None` instead of `== None`.

Comment: I'd personnally would subclass the default help command, it'd be much easier. You can check out this [guide](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96), it's very well documented and really easy to understand

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I'll add that link in my answer to help him out, seeing as he accepted it.

Comment: Oh that make sense. Alright thanks for the help again. I'll also change `== None` to `is None`!